# How do I validate the uniqueness of a has_many :through join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users and issues joined by a votership model. Users can vote on issues. They can either vote up or down (which is recorded in the votership model). First, I want to be able to prevent users from casting multiple votes in one direction. Second, I want to allow users to cast the opposite vote. So, if they voted up, they should still be able to vote down which will replace the up vote. Users should never be able to vote on an issue twice. Here are my files:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :users, :through => :associations

  has_many :voterships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :voterships

  belongs_to :app

  STATUS = ['Open', 'Closed']

  validates :subject, :presence => true,
                      :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :description, :presence => true,
                          :length => { :maximum => 200 }
  validates :type, :presence => true
  validates :status, :presence => true

  def cast_vote_up!(user_id, direction)
    voterships.create!(:issue_id => self.id, :user_id   => user_id,
                                             :direction => direction)
  end
end


class Votership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :issue
end

class VotershipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:votership][:issue_id])
    @issue.cast_vote_up!(current_user.id, "up")
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  has_many :associations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :issues, :through => :associations

  has_many :voterships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :issues, :through => :voterships
end
```

Answer (score 12):

You would put the uniqueness constraint on the `Votership` model. You don't need to put validations on the association itself.

```
class Votership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :issue

  validates :issue_id, :uniqueness => {:scope=>:user_id}
end
```

This means a user can only have a single vote on a given issue (up or down).

Comment: Hi, this works but it raises an `ActiveRecord::ValidateError` exception when adding a duplicated entry in the join table. What is the best way to associate the record or fail without raising the exception? Thanks

Comment: Isn't it supposed to raise a validate error? If you want only one vote per issue, per user, then you either need to remove the previous vote (and replace it with the new one), or rescue the error when it comes up and decide what to do. It sounds like it's failing validation for a duplicate entry, which is exactly what it's supposed to do, no?

Comment: Yes, I just ask because I'm new to rails and I wondered if there was a better way (something like a `<<` that doesn't raise an exception) that rescue the exception. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I guess it depends on how you want the situation to be handled. If it should never happen in production, then you can let it be, and let your app throw errors (because if it should never happen, then it indicates a bug that needs to be fixed, and therefore should not be covered up by catching the error). If you need it to throw an error, but then rescue, then you can simply rescue. You could also check to see if there's an existing vote in place, and if so, take some appropriate action to either invalidate the new vote, or remove the old vote, whatever is appropriate for your app.

Comment: So in general when you have a `has_many` (or something like this) and you need to add an object to this collection the right thing to do is to verify if it already exists before to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship models:

```
class Person
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :computers, through: :accounts
end

class Account
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :computer

  scope :administrators, -> { where(role: 'administrator') }
end

class Computer
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :people, through: :accounts
end
```

This is how it is called

`person.accounts.administrators.map(&:computer)`

We can do this better using ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge!

`person.computers.merge(Account.administrators)`

---

Ref: https://coderwall.com/p/9xk6ra/rails-filter-using-join-model-on-has_many-through