# Why is updating a form duplicating my form fields and duplicating records with habtm and nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a nested form inside a parent form that allows you to add fields inside the parent form. The idea is that a book can have many schools and the school belongs to the book(habtm) relationship. here are my models:

books.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :schools, :reject_if => :find_school, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true


def find_school(school)
    if existing_school = School.find_by_school_name(school['school_name'])
       self.schools << existing_school
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

school.rb

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :books

    validates :school_name, :address, presence: true
    #validates_uniqueness_of :school_name
end
```

In my form for the book I have this setup:

```
<div id="school" class="field">
      <h3>Schools reading this book (add the name and full address of the school)</h3>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :schools, :wrapper => 'inline' do |builder| %>  
        <%= render 'school_fields', :f => builder %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add school', f, :schools, :render_options => {:wrapper => 'inline' }, :class => 'fa fa-plus' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

In here it should render the fields but I get this

[image: the fields in the edit form after update]

The issue i have is that in my book.rb model the `find_school` method keeps returning multiple values of the same books when I update the book. The idea is that the `find_school` method basically stops duplicate schools being created as records and just assigns them as a relationship to the book instead. What I am finding is that this `self.schools << existing_school` on update just keeps duplicating the fields in the edit form and adds the fields as entries on the item when I check in the params output.

Can anyone help with this

Comment: Have you considered using a scoped validation, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8247971/382982)?

Comment: Your title suggests that updating is causing duplicate entries to be created, but you describe trying to prevent duplicates from being created using find_school, which is it?

Comment: Also, have you tried a `puts School.find_by_school_name(school['school_name'])` to see if it is returning correctly? I suspect you need something more like `School.find_by_school_name(school[school.name])`

Comment: I tried those above but nothing happened. The issue is stopping duplicate entries being created by find_school

Comment: Where is the code that saves the book? Where is the code that calls `find_school`. To me, it seems like the problem is this. 1) Book has no schools. 2) Add school to book, press save. 3) `find_school` is called and adds schools to the book's school list. 4) The book's school list already contained all of its schools, so the list is duplicated.

Comment: Max I think you hit the nail on the head there as that is whats happenin but i am not sure how to fix it?